# Javascript + Load AJAX function on page load + Pass Javascript vars to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have again a little problem with a javascript (i am a real noob regardin that). This time I would like to load an AJAX function on page load in order to save some javascript variables to php sessions. I figured out thats the best way to pass javascript vars to php. If there is a better way (besides cookies), dont hesitate to let me know :)

For now I would like to:
-pass javascript variables to an external php page on page load
-save variables in php
-use the php variables without pagereload

Here is my script so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function save_visitor_details() {
        $(function() {
            var visitor_country = geoip_country_name();
            var visitor_region = geoip_region_name();
            var visitor_lat = geoip_latitude();
            var visitor_lon = geoip_longitude();
            var visitor_city = geoip_city();
            var visitor_zip = geoip_postal_code();
            var dataString = 'visitor_country='+ visitor_country +'&visitor_region='+ visitor_region +'&visitor_lat='+ visitor_lat +'&visitor_lon='+ visitor_lon +'&visitor_city='+ visitor_city +'&visitor_zip='+ visitor_zip;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/visitor_details.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function(res) {
                       alert ("saved");
                       //$('#result').html(res);<-- should contain variables from inc/visitor_details.php
                    }); 
                }  
            });
            return false;
        }
});
```

Thanks in advance!
Edit: I changed it a little and got it to work by adding the javascript variables into a hidden form, submit the form with the ajax script above and save variables into php session array at the backend php file.
Thanks any1 for your time!!!

Comment: where is php variable?? on `nc/visitor_details.php`?

Comment: What's the actual question, as I see no errors with this script.

Comment: Hi Guys, php variables are "generated" at "inc/visitor_details.php". The script doesnt work for me as the variables are not saved to php when i load index.php and the alert is not triggered. (at least it doesnt work for me right now)

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is the question here. But here are a few advices.

- rather than serializing the data yourself, you should rather let jQuery do that for you:

  ```
  $.post('inc/visitor_details.php', {country: geoip_country_name() /* stuff */}, function(data) {
    alert('ok!'); alert(data);
  });
  ```
- be aware that, by passing data to your server using Javascript, users *can* send whatever data they want, including fake data. So handle it with care.

Then entire process may looks like this:

```
/* javascript */
$(document).ready(function() {
    function save_visitor_details() {
        $.post('inc/visitor_details.php', {
            country: geoip_country_name(),
            region: geoip_region_name(),
            lat: geoip_latitude(),
            lon: geoip_longitude(),
            city: geoip_city(),
            zip: geoip_postal_code()
        }, function(data) {
            /* do whatever you want here */
            alert(data);
        }, 'json');
    }

    save_visitor_details();
});

/* PHP */
<?php
$keys = array('country', 'region', 'lat', 'lon', 'city', 'zip');
$output = array();

foreach($keys as $key) {
    do_some_stuff($_POST[$key]);
    $output[$key] = $_POST[$key];
}

header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo json_encode($output);
?>
```

Comment: Hi Zopieux, Thanks for your quick reply. I give you an example what I would like to have at the end: visitor comes at index.php -> javascript gets his info and saves them into variables -> saved variables are send to visitor_details.php -> sent variables are saved as php variables -> php variables are returned to index.php -- everything without a page reload from the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript:**

```
var http = createRequestObject() ;

function createRequestObject(){
    var obj;
    var browser = navigator.appName;

    if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
        obj = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }else{
        obj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return obj;
}

function sendReq(str){  
    http.open('get', str);
    http.onreadystatechange = handleResponse;
    http.send(null);
}

sendReq("someurl?var=yourvar");
```

**Php:**

```
$var = $_GET['var']; // use some security here.
```

Comment: He's already using jQuery, I don't see the point of handling the XMLHTTP stuff here. Moreover, it seems he wants to use POST.

Comment: Thanks anyways zozo, but I came up with a little different solution. see my post above.